# How to install plugins in sbt 0.11.2?

Tags: sbt

I want to install [Lifty](http://lifty.github.com/).

I have created `c:\sbt\plugins\build.sbt` with the following single line:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.lifty" % "lifty" % "1.7.4")
```

When I execute `sbt lifty` in the project directory, I only get the following error:

> [error] Not a valid command: lifty

How do I configure sbt for the plugin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The global plugin definition has to go into the *.sbt* subdirectory of your home directory:

```
~/.sbt/plugins/plugin.sbt
```

Actually the name (*plugin.sbt*) does not matter as long as the suffix is *.sbt*.